# Map response from GitHub API to React.js with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making a request on the github api with axios

`api.github.com/users/fariasmateuss/repos`

And I try to map the data

```js
interface RepositoryProps {
  full_name: string;
  description: string;
  html_url: string;
  stargazers_count: number;
  forks_count: number;
}

const Repository: React.FC = () => {
  const [repo, setRepo] = useState<RepositoryProps | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchRepositoryData(): Promise<void> {
      const { data } = await api.get<RepositoryProps>(
        '/users/fariasmateuss/repos',
      );

      setRepo(data);
    }

    fetchRepositoryData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {repo.map(repositories => (
        <div key={repositories.id} className="repo">
          <div className="top-side">
            <header className="header-repo">
              <RiBookMarkLine className="icon-repo" />
              <Link className="anchor-repo" to="/">
                {repositories.full_name}
              </Link>
            </header>
            <p className="description">{repositories.description}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul className="bottom-side">
              <li className="icon-wrap">
                <RiStarLine className="icon-repo" />
                <span className="stars">{repositories.stargazers_count}</span>
              </li>
              <li className="icon-wrap">
                <AiOutlineFork className="icon-repo" />
                <span className="forks">{repositories.stargazers_count}</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Repository;
```

However, it returns error below

> const repo: RepositoryProps | null Object is possibly 'null'

and

> (parameter) repositories: any Parameter 'repositories' implicitly has
> an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Would anyone know how to help me or tell me how I could solve this?

Comment: Your request is failing and you get a NULL result, you need to simplify your code in order to isolate the issue, is it a connection issue, an authentication issue, a typo in your code etc.

Answer (score 1):

> const repo: RepositoryProps | null Object is possibly 'null'

I assume this error was caused by the line, `{repo.map(repositories => (`? TypeScript is giving you the error as `repo` on this line could be `null`. This would happen while the fetch request is loading, or if there were an error in fetching, such as a network failure. You can fix this by accommodating for this case, for example by using optional chaining:

```
{repo?.map(repositories => (
  /* ... */
)}
```